# Django - form is always not valid

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am new to Django, I have to do a simple web page to register people. Some names is in Portuguese, but it does not matter. I do not know what I am doing wrong, maybe I am sending empty data to the view, but I am not sure.
view.py:

```
def get_form(request):
    logger = logging.getLogger('django')
    logger.info("Request")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logger.info("POST method")
        form = cadastroForm(request.POST)
        logger.info(form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():         
            logger.info("Valid")
            insert_data(form.cleaned_data['nome'], form.cleaned_data['mat'], form.cleaned_data['telefone'], form.cleaned_data['email'])

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('all-borrowed'))
        else:
            logger.info("Not Valid")
    else:
        form = cadastroForm()
```

html page:

```
{% block page_content %}


<h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 5%; font-size: 64px;">Cadastro</h1>
<form action="../../views.py" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 40%;" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" style="margin-left: 30px" maxlength="100" required><br><br>
    <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" style="margin-left: 10px" required><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="margin-left: 36px" required>
    <p style="margin-top: 15px;">Frequenta o IESB:
    <input type="radio" id="iesb_sim" name="iesb" value="Yes" required><label for="iesb_sim" style="margin-left: 5px">Sim</label>
    <input type="radio" id="iesb_nao" name="iesb" value="No" required checked="checked"><label for="iesb_nao" style="margin-left: 5px">Não</label>
    </p>
    <label for="mat">Matrícula:</label>
    <input type="text" id="mat" name="mat">
    <br><br>   
    <input type="file"  style="margin-bottom: 18px" id="myFile" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="margin: auto; display: block;">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("iesb_sim").addEventListener("change", function(){
        document.getElementById("mat").disabled = false;
    })
    document.getElementById("iesb_nao").addEventListener("change", function(){
        document.getElementById("mat").disabled = true;
    })
</script>
{% endblock page_content %}
```

forms.py:

```
class cadastroForm(forms.Form):
    nome = forms.CharField(label="Nome completo", required=True, max_length=100)
    telefone = forms.CharField(label="Telefone", required=True, max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", required=True)
    b_iesb = forms.RadioSelect(choices=["Yes", "No"])
    mat = forms.IntegerField(label="Matrícula")
    foto = forms.ImageField(label="Foto")
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        nome = cleaned_data.get("nome")
        tele = cleaned_data.get("telefone")
        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        b_iesb = cleaned_data.get("iesb")
        mat = cleaned_data.get("mat")
        #foto = cleaned_data.get("filename")

        if not nome.istitle():
            nome = nome.Title()

        if re.search("[a-zA-Z]", tele) != None:
            raise ValidationError(_(
                    "O número de telefone não pode possuir letras"
            ))

        validate_email(email)

        if b_iesb == "Yes":
            if mat == None:
                raise ValidationError(_(
                    "Se frequenta o IESB, deve possuir uma matrícula"
                ))
```

- Fill free to recommend updates, what I can do better with Django

I need the name, the phone number, email, if it is a Yes at the radio button I need the registration, and a photo file. The error I am getting the telefone, and foto is required, even I sent those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer to the question

Make sure to **return the `cleaned_data`*** in the end. When the `clean()` method does not return data the error "XYZ is required" is thrown because it "did not survive" your `clean()` method (simply because it was not returned). Stick to the following template:

```py
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # Your form fields here

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        # Perform your custom validation and cleaning here

        # Always return cleaned_data
        return cleaned_data
```

#### Additional recommendations

The end of your view function probably returns a call to the `render` function which gets passed: `request`, `template` and `context`. That context can hold the form. That form can be accessed from within the template and saves you a lot of typing work.

```py
# your view function
def get_form(request):
    [... your logic ...]
    return render(request, 'your-template.html', context={form: form})
```

your template:

```html
{% block page_content %}


<h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 5%; font-size: 64px;">Cadastro</h1>
<form action="../../views.py" style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 40%;" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    {{ form }}

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="margin: auto; display: block;">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById("iesb_sim").addEventListener("change", function(){
        document.getElementById("mat").disabled = false;
    })
```

(more [info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#the-template))

Comment: It worked, thank you. I was already returning a `render`. When I ask for the file is saying:**This field is required**